# Azure Face API - How to see stored face images/templates?

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-services

I am consuming the Azure Face API (Detection and Find Similars), but I do not see any documentation that explains how to access the stored data in the Azure's platform (in the UI of the Azure's website).

According to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/legal/cognitive-services/face/data-privacy-security), only facial templates are stored. But, how can I see them? Are these resources accessible for devs? Any other data stored?

Answer (score 0):

By default, we can access the data with blob storage as the default storage in azure portal. By default, blob storage cannot be accessed in the public manner. It will be private, and we need to have it accessed publicly. Using the shared access signature (SAS) we can provide secured access to the resources in storage account.

Use the below procedure to get the SAS token and access them in API calls.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]